# Elasticsearch how to correctly provide a negative boost in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to give a negative boost to push results down in the ranking if they have 'b-stock' in the title.

Here is my code:

```
'body' => [
    'size' => 15,
    'query' => [
        'boosting' => [
            'positive' =>[
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        ['query_string' => [
                            'default_field' => 'title_tag',
                            'query' => $term
                        ]],
                        ['query_string' => [
                            'default_field' => 'name',
                            'query' => $term
                        ]],
                        ['query_string' => [
                            'default_field' => 'description',
                            'query' => $term
                        ]],
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            'negative' => [
                'term' => [
                    'name' => 'B-Stock'
                ]
            ],
            'negative_boost' => 2
        ]
    ]
]
```

However this seems to have no affect on the results even if I remove the term array from the 'negative' array the same results set is returned.